# spring boot how to join tables from different microservices

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am developing application using microservices architecture. 
I have Authentication Service and Courses Service.
In Authentication Service there is a User class with @Entity annotation.
In Courses Service there is a Course class with @Entity annotation.
I want to make field Set courses in User class.
But User class and Course class are in different services how to do this?
Please if there is related article give me link.

Comment: don't you think that it's easier to post your code than describing it?

Comment: i fear this is not convenient (not feasible) with jpa, nor with "micro service" architecture ...what would be convenient, would be a third microservice, which binds(finds/reverse) them together...but without jpa (rather custom dtos) ..what you can have are ["multiple persistence units/contexts/datasources"](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7), but (i still fear) you cannot mix them (the sample shows only separated domains)

Comment: ..and for me a good sample for "over-micro..ing"   ..or over-scoping. as a "rule of thumb" i would recommend: [1-few] "database" ("domain"s)  -> 1 "micro service" ..and even better/wider: 1 "team" -> 1 "micro service"